# How to efficently handle errors in Spring: Could not resolve view with name 'forward:/oauth/error'

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, spring-boot

I have my rest api that create this error in response when oauth2 client_id is not valid.

```
{"timestamp":"2016-10-06T05:26:31.367+0000","status":500,"error":"Internal Server Error","exception":"org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.NoSuchClientException","message":"No client with requested id: backoffice","path":"/oauth/authorize"}
```

Server side I have in my log :

```
Looking up handler method for path /oauth/authorize
Did not find handler method for [/oauth/authorize]
Handling ClientRegistrationException error: No client with requested id: backoffice
Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Could not resolve view with name 'forward:/oauth/error' in servlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'] with root cause
javax.servlet.ServletException: Could not resolve view with name 'forward:/oauth/error' in servlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1237)
    ...
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

### Question: What is the best way to prevent server to give him the class exception and to handle this error ?

I have tried to follow the recommandation with `@ControllerAdvice` as described in this [article](http://www.journaldev.com/2651/spring-mvc-exception-handling-controlleradvice-exceptionhandler-handlerexceptionresolver) but the code never pass through the breakpoint:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class GlobalExceptionHandler {
    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(GlobalExceptionHandler.class);
    @ExceptionHandler(NoSuchClientException.class)
    public String handleNoSuchClientException(HttpServletRequest request, Exception ex){
        logger.info("NoSuchClientException Occured:: URL="+request.getRequestURL());
        return "no_such_client_error";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the annotation `@ResponseBody` to each `ControllerAdvice` method.

Comment: If you annotate the whole `ControllerAdvice` class, it works as well. Tested on Spring 5.3.4.

Answer (score -2):

The sections **Configuring the Endpoint URLs** and **Customizing the Error Handling** in the following link - http://projects.spring.io/spring-security-oauth/docs/oauth2.html may be a good place to start.

I would personally suggest using **WebResponseExceptionTranslator** so that you can handle different Exceptions differently. A way to include this in your configuration can be found here - [How to inject WebResponseExceptionTranslator in TokenEndPoint Spring oAuth2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32912460/how-to-inject-webresponseexceptiontranslator-in-tokenendpoint-spring-oauth2)

An easier way out would be configuring "/oauth/error" endpoint as a controller method in your project which dishes out a standard response on error in oauth flow. But this would rob you of the freedom to change responses based on different exceptions.